# Storing vector of doubles into a text file

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

I don't have any experience with file handling so it must seem like a silly question but I have a big vector and I want to store it into a text file. I have written the following piece of code for it:

```
std::vector<double> finalOutput; //vector which i am storing in file

std::ofstream outputFile;

outputFile.open("Output.txt");

for (auto& t : finalOutput)
    outputFile << t << '\n';

outputFile.close();
```

The values in the vector are something like 26.1714237331405, 26.7561856347912, 25.2838784640364 but when i check the file it is getting stored like 26.1714, 26.7562, 25.2839.

I want to store all the digits after the decimal point and not just 4 digits after decimal point. How can I do that?

P.S: I tried to typecast it by writing it as follows but that didn't work.

```
outputFile << (long double) t << '\n';
```

Comment: Next time select the code and use the {} button to format the code.

Comment: `outputFile << std::setprecision(15) << t << '\n'`

Comment: In addition to Igor Tandenik's comment: also add `#include <iomanip>`